# The difference between more crucial or more important

Tags: difference, comparative-constructions

In the examples below it seems that using 'more important' is correct. Would you agree and why?

- If studying to be an engineer, it is obvious that studying calculus is **more crucial** than studying Shakespeare
- If studying to be an engineer, it is obvious that studying calculus is **more important** than studying Shakespeare

Comment: The first sentence is wrong. Something is either crucial (critical to the success of) or not crucial. It is not more crucial (a bit like unique or dead). Importance on the other hand ranges from slight to extreme. Some things are much more important than others.

Comment: @RonaldSole [this](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/crucial) shows both superlative and comparative forms exist. And sentences like *"As markets become increasingly turbulent, the predictability of the framework established and implemented by politics has become even more crucial"* make total sense to me...

Comment: @AndrewTobilko In context though, we would say something IS crucial, or IS more important, not IS more crucial. I think this question deserves a proper answer explaining why "has become even more crucial" is OK, but "has become more crucial" is not.

Comment: Most so-called-absolute adjectives *can* be compared, but only in limited contexts. There is such a thing as "more unique" and "more dead" and "more crucial"

Comment: That being said, there's no way to read "more crucial" as being correct in the OP's context.